# Getting 16GB of RAM - what to check for in motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have a Gigabyte X58A-UD3R motherboard (i7 930 processor) and I'd like to buy two 8GB-each DDR3 memory banks.

Are there restrictions on the kind of memory I should buy? I mean: compatibility issues I should be aware to have the memory banks working and/or perform better.

Comment: You should check the user manual for the mobo. See what is the Max it supports and if it's dual channel or not

Comment: I already have 6 GB DDR3 banks installed and they work great, so I think DDR3 should be supported. I should also search for a "max amount of memory supported" ?

Comment: Well if you have ddr3 currently installed, then that's a no brainer. But yes, check the max. And mainly find the documentation for that mobo

Comment: The documentation is here: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3449#manual. And I think I got what I wanted: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3449#sp

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Since the max is 24, 2x8gig should work since it's a dual channel

Comment: Let a computer profession or an experienced person do this for you and dont do it yourself or you will damage your pc

Comment: @TechLife but if he doesn't do it himself, he won't learn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, it is always best to check the Hardware Compatibility List (HCL) for your motherboard, and your OS (especially for Linux).

Gigabyte almost always publishes a CPU and RAM HCL for each model of board they release. Yours are available at the top of your products support page, here: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3449#

A community driven HCL for linux is available here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/hcl/index.php

Some distros have more specific or more official HCLs, like Ubuntu's available here: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/ and here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport

Windows has a compatibility search tool available here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/Home?Language=en-US
Most modern hardware is generally compatible with windows, though there may be some variance between windows 7 and windows 8+, just as there were between XP and Vista.